# binlog not recording DML statement in mysqlcluster

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-cluster, mysqlbinlog, binlog

I have created a MySQL NDB Cluster consisting of 2 data node, 1 mgm node and 1 mysqld for testing. Also i have created a slave for NDB to INNODB replication. My binlog are not recording DML statement because of which i am not able to do Point in time recovery for NDB CLuster and also DML Statements are not replicating on slave, only the tables are being created with no row entries.

ndb_binlog_index table on master is empty with no entries.

## Below is my.cnf file for ndb-cluster mysqld.

```
[mysqld]

datadir=/var/lib/mysql

socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log

pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

log_bin=/home/binlog/ndbcluster-bin

log-bin-index=ndbcluster-bin.index

binlog_format=ROW

user=mysql

#NDB

ndbcluster

ndb-nodeid=101

default-storage-engine=NDB

ndb-connectstring=192.168.56.101,192.168.56.102

[mysql_cluster]

ndb-connectstring=192.168.56.101,192.168.56.102

[ndb_mgmd]

config-dir=/usr/mysql-cluster

config-file=/etc/config.ini
```

## Version Information

```
 version                  | 8.0.20-cluster                       |

| version_comment          | MySQL Cluster Community Server - GPL |
```

## binlog variables as shown

```
mysql> show variables like '%bin%';

+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                                  | Value                               |
+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| bind_address                                   | *                                   |

| binlog_cache_size                              | 32768                               |

| binlog_checksum                                | CRC32                               |

| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates        | OFF                                 |

| binlog_encryption                              | OFF                                 |

| binlog_error_action                            | ABORT_SERVER                        |

| binlog_expire_logs_seconds                     | 2592000                             |

| binlog_format                                  | ROW                                 |

| binlog_group_commit_sync_delay                 | 0                                   |

| binlog_group_commit_sync_no_delay_count        | 0                                   |

| binlog_gtid_simple_recovery                    | ON                                  |

| binlog_max_flush_queue_time                    | 0                                   |

| binlog_order_commits                           | ON                                  |

| binlog_rotate_encryption_master_key_at_startup | OFF                                 |

| binlog_row_event_max_size                      | 8192                                |

| binlog_row_image                               | FULL                                |

| binlog_row_metadata                            | MINIMAL                             |

| binlog_row_value_options                       |                                     |

| binlog_rows_query_log_events                   | OFF                                 |

| binlog_stmt_cache_size                         | 32768                               |

| binlog_transaction_compression                 | OFF                                 |

| binlog_transaction_compression_level_zstd      | 3                                   |

| binlog_transaction_dependency_history_size     | 25000                               |

| binlog_transaction_dependency_tracking         | COMMIT_ORDER                        |

| innodb_api_enable_binlog                       | OFF                                 |

| log_bin                                        | ON                                  |

| log_bin_basename                               | /home/binlog/ndbcluster-bin         |

| log_bin_index                                  | /var/lib/mysql/ndbcluster-bin.index |

| log_bin_trust_function_creators                | OFF                                 |

| log_bin_use_v1_row_events                      | OFF                                 |

| log_statements_unsafe_for_binlog               | ON                                  |

| max_binlog_cache_size                          | 18446744073709547520                |

| max_binlog_size                                | 1073741824                          |

| max_binlog_stmt_cache_size                     | 18446744073709547520                |

| mysqlx_bind_address                            | *                                   |

| ndb_log_bin                                    | OFF                                 |

| ndb_log_binlog_index                           | ON                                  |

| ndb_report_thresh_binlog_epoch_slip            | 10                                  |

| ndb_report_thresh_binlog_mem_usage             | 10                                  |

| ndbinfo_database                               | ndbinfo                             |

| ndbinfo_max_bytes                              | 0                                   |

| ndbinfo_max_rows                               | 10                                  |

| ndbinfo_offline                                | OFF                                 |

| ndbinfo_show_hidden                            | OFF                                 |

| ndbinfo_table_prefix                           | ndb$                                |

| ndbinfo_version                                | 524308                              |

| sql_log_bin                                    | ON                                  |

| sync_binlog                                    | 1                                   |

+------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
48 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

## Below a test for showing no entries being made in binlog.

```
mysql> show binlog events in 'ndbcluster-bin.000003';

+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| Log_name              | Pos | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                      |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 |   4 | Format_desc    |         1 |         125 | Server ver: 8.0.20-cluster, Binlog ver: 4 |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 125 | Previous_gtids |         1 |         156 |                                           |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> create database test;

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)


mysql> use test

Database changed

mysql>

mysql> create table employees (staff_no int(10));

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.29 sec)

mysql>

mysql> show binlog events in 'ndbcluster-bin.000003';

+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name              | Pos | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                                               |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 |   4 | Format_desc    |         1 |         125 | Server ver: 8.0.20-cluster, Binlog ver: 4                          |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 125 | Previous_gtids |         1 |         156 |                                                                    |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 156 | Anonymous_Gtid |         1 |         233 | SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'                               |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 233 | Query          |         1 |         341 | create database test /* xid=84 */                                  |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 341 | Anonymous_Gtid |         1 |         418 | SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'                               |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 418 | Query          |         1 |         547 | use `test`; create table employees (staff_no int(10)) /* xid=92 */ |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> insert into employees values (1234), (3242);

Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> commit;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>

mysql> select * from employees;

+----------+
| staff_no |
+----------+
|     3242 |
|     1234 |
+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> show binlog events in 'ndbcluster-bin.000003';

+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Log_name              | Pos | Event_type     | Server_id | End_log_pos | Info                                                               |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 |   4 | Format_desc    |         1 |         125 | Server ver: 8.0.20-cluster, Binlog ver: 4                          |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 125 | Previous_gtids |         1 |         156 |                                                                    |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 156 | Anonymous_Gtid |         1 |         233 | SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'                               |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 233 | Query          |         1 |         341 | create database test /* xid=84 */                                  |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 341 | Anonymous_Gtid |         1 |         418 | SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'                               |
| ndbcluster-bin.000003 | 418 | Query          |         1 |         547 | use `test`; create table employees (staff_no int(10)) /* xid=92 */ |
+-----------------------+-----+----------------+-----------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> use mysql

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A


Database changed

mysql>

mysql> select * from ndb_binlog_index;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I have also checked binlog with mysqlbinlog  but it also doesnt show any insert entries.

```
{
[root@ndb-cluster-mysqld1 binlog]# mysqlbinlog -v --base64-output=DECODE-ROWS ndbcluster-bin.000003

/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=1*/;
/*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
DELIMITER /*!*/;
# at 4
#200528 14:20:15 server id 1  end_log_pos 125 CRC32 0x3ad8779c  Start: binlog v 4, server v 8.0.20-cluster created 200528 14:20:15
# Warning: this binlog is either in use or was not closed properly.
# at 125
#200528 14:20:15 server id 1  end_log_pos 156 CRC32 0x71313f0a  Previous-GTIDs
# [empty]
# at 156
#200528 14:21:12 server id 1  end_log_pos 233 CRC32 0x0f5b463e  Anonymous_GTID  last_committed=0        sequence_number=1       rbr_only=no     original_committed_timestamp=1590655872244131   immediate_commit_timestamp=1590655872244131     transaction_length=185
# original_commit_timestamp=1590655872244131 (2020-05-28 14:21:12.244131 IST)
# immediate_commit_timestamp=1590655872244131 (2020-05-28 14:21:12.244131 IST)
/*!80001 SET @@session.original_commit_timestamp=1590655872244131*//*!*/;
/*!80014 SET @@session.original_server_version=80020*//*!*/;
/*!80014 SET @@session.immediate_server_version=80020*//*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'/*!*/;
# at 233
#200528 14:21:12 server id 1  end_log_pos 341 CRC32 0xb8313dcf  Query   thread_id=16    exec_time=0     error_code=0    Xid = 84
SET TIMESTAMP=1590655872/*!*/;
SET @@session.pseudo_thread_id=16/*!*/;
SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=1, @@session.sql_auto_is_null=0, @@session.unique_checks=1, @@session.autocommit=1/*!*/;
SET @@session.sql_mode=1168113696/*!*/;
SET @@session.auto_increment_increment=1, @@session.auto_increment_offset=1/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8mb4 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=255,@@session.collation_connection=255,@@session.collation_server=255/*!*/;
SET @@session.lc_time_names=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.collation_database=DEFAULT/*!*/;
/*!80011 SET @@session.default_collation_for_utf8mb4=255*//*!*/;
/*!80016 SET @@session.default_table_encryption=0*//*!*/;
create database test
/*!*/;
# at 341
#200528 14:22:35 server id 1  end_log_pos 418 CRC32 0x562df9ef  Anonymous_GTID  last_committed=1        sequence_number=2       rbr_only=no     original_committed_timestamp=1590655955983593   immediate_commit_timestamp=1590655955983593     transaction_length=206
# original_commit_timestamp=1590655955983593 (2020-05-28 14:22:35.983593 IST)
# immediate_commit_timestamp=1590655955983593 (2020-05-28 14:22:35.983593 IST)
/*!80001 SET @@session.original_commit_timestamp=1590655955983593*//*!*/;
/*!80014 SET @@session.original_server_version=80020*//*!*/;
/*!80014 SET @@session.immediate_server_version=80020*//*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'ANONYMOUS'/*!*/;
# at 418
#200528 14:22:35 server id 1  end_log_pos 547 CRC32 0x8618cc05  Query   thread_id=16    exec_time=0     error_code=0    Xid = 92
use `test`/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1590655955/*!*/;
/*!80013 SET @@session.sql_require_primary_key=0*//*!*/;
create table employees (staff_no int(10))
/*!*/;
SET @@SESSION.GTID_NEXT= 'AUTOMATIC' /* added by mysqlbinlog */ /*!*/;
DELIMITER ;
# End of log file
/*!50003 SET COMPLETION_TYPE=@OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE*/;
/*!50530 SET @@SESSION.PSEUDO_SLAVE_MODE=0*/;

}
```

Please help i am stuck on this since last 2 days.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding ndb_log_bin=ON in my.cnf file since ndb_log_bin is disabled by default in mysql 8.0.16 and higher.